# The probability of the triangle made from connecting three random points on the perimeter of a circle containing the circle’s center

Tags: probability

I can’t figure out what I’m doing wrong.

Let’s say we randomly select two points on the circle’s perimeter. If we connect them to the center, we’ll have two lines that cut the circle in two other point on the opposite side of the circle.

For the triangle to contain the center, the third point must be somewhere between those two points.

If the angle between the two lines is $\theta$ radians, then the probability of the triangle containing the center is $\frac{\theta}{2\pi} $, where $\theta$ can range from 0 to $\pi $.

$$\int_0^\pi\frac{\theta}{2\pi}\, d\theta = \frac{\pi^2}{4\pi} - 0 = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

But I looked up the question in the Internet and the answer is supposed to be $\frac{1}{4}$. No matter how much I think about it, I can’t figure out what I’m doing wrong.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to divide by the range of integration (i.e. $\pi$) to normalise the probability to $1$.

To take a simpler case, suppose we want the probability that a random number chosen in $[0,10]$ is less than $5$. Then we integrate $\int_0^{10}f(x)\;dx$, where $f(x)=1$ if $x<5$ and $0$ if $x\ge 5$. The result is $5$; and we have to divide this by the range of  integration, $10$, to get the correct answer $\frac12$.